# How to replace new Function (string) constructors with simple functions

Tags: javascript, function, security, constructor, owasp

I would like to know, if it is not a duplicate question, how is it possible to convert a function created with the Function() constructor to a simple function. To explain better the problem i will do an example:

```
    function foo() {
       var funcString = "console.log('hello'); var x = document.getElementById('content-1x');"
           obj.assignFunction = new Function(funcString);
    }
```

In this case, funcString is a function that is passed to as a string.

At first glance, it all seems easy, since you just put the lines of code into an anonymous function which is assigned to obj.assignFunction as following example:

```
function foo(){
  obj.assignFunction = function(){
    console.log('hello');
    var x = document.getElementById('content-1x')
  }
}
```

But my problem is that I get the function string from an attribute of an HTML element and it could change in other pages.
For example, could get functionString from these HTML span

```
<span id="elem1" functionString="console.log('hello'); var x = 3*3">
```

So, as you can see, the function string can change.
In order not to be dispersed, I conclude with the precise question:

**Is possible replace a new Function(functionString) constructor with function(){//functionString converted into code lines} also if functionString can be based on elements attribute "functionString"?**

Comment: *I get the function string from an attribute of an HTML element* This is *really really weird*. Consider if a different approach is viable - your codebase will be better off.

Comment: @CertainPerformance It's old code that i can't change from scratch to don't brak all application :( so, to cover the risk i can just convert "new Function()" to function(){}. Or if exists other approach it will be sure better, but i have not idea

Comment: Maybe you could store the function string (or the function that has been defined from it) somewhere and use the stored version. The idea is that if the the HTML attribute changes, your stored copy would be unaffected.